# Excel 2007 VBA Problem setting Axis Title

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I need help setting the X and Y axes title inside Excel 2007 VBA.  It keeps complaining about "Object required":

```
Sub macro2()

Dim xAxis As Axis

icount = 1

Charts.Add
Charts(icount).Name = iskewplane & "deg Skew Plane"
Charts(icount).Activate

Set xAxis = Charts(icount).Axes(xlCategory)
With xAxis
    .Axis
    .AxisTitle.Text = "Theta (deg)"
End With
```

Is there something wrong in my code?  I tried recording the macro during setting the axis title name, but the macro is blank during the name setting.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Option Explicit` because `iCount` wasn't defined and `iskewplane` wasn't either.

Here is the right code:

```
Sub mac()
    Dim xAxis As Axis
    Dim iCount As Integer
    iCount = 1
    Charts.Add
     Charts(iCount).Name = "deg Skew Plane"
    Charts(iCount).Activate

    Set xAxis = Charts(iCount).Axes(xlCategory)
    With xAxis
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Caption = "Theta (deg)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: .HasTitle = True

That was what I was missing, thanks!  I have the .HasTitle=True further down in the code, but it needs one before I can set it.  Duh.

Comment: I had exactly the same mistake: the .HasTitle was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You first have to create the AxisTitle object - an axis doesn't automatically have one. This is done by setting `Axis.HasTitle = True` - a slightly unusual method.