# Run-time Error '424': Object Required when setting AxisTitle.Text

Tags: excel, vba

I edited a graph and captured a macro while doing so. Then I wanted to copy and paste the vba to some other vba file. I did not change anything and kept the whole code. But at the following line always there is the Object required error (424):

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Kraft"
```

The context is:

```
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Messung 1"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Messung 1"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 9).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 9).Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    ...
End With
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Kraft"
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: All other parts work except for assigning the AxisTitle? What I suggest is you work explicitly with objects. Abandon using *Selection* and *ActiveChart*. Can you elaborate what you're trying? Are you creating charts or the charts already exist and you only need to format / modify it?

Answer (score 3):

Although you have recorded using a macro and it should automatically play back, it doesn't seem to in the case of label text (I had the same problem).

The solution is to use this code instead, gathered from the microsoft website

```
With Charts("Chart1").Axes(xlCategory) 
    .HasTitle = True 
    .AxisTitle.Text = "July Sales" 
End With
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839276.aspx

I also found the solution in this stack overflow post
[Excel 2007 VBA Problem setting Axis Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041428/excel-2007-vba-problem-setting-axis-title)

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, and I have tested the method and it works on Office 365 Excel(Latest version).

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart Name").Activate
With ActiveChart
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "X Axis Title"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Y Axis Title"
End With
```

By the way, I also found that the Macro Recorded by Excel for ActiveChart will return this error. I found [this link](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/516320-charting-problem-with-activechart-setsourcedata.html) and some explanation of ActiveChart of VBA, maybe it will help.

> There are two distinct types of charts in Excel:
>   1. One is a chart consisting of an entire sheet (a chart sheet). A chart sheet is not a worksheet. Charts(1) is the first chart sheet in
>   the workbook.
>   2. The other is a chart placed on top of a worksheet - "embedded" on the worksheet. The worksheet chart has a container around it called a
>   "Chart Object". Therefore, you have to identify the chart object
>   before you can specify the particular chart you want to refer
>   to...ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.
>
> If you want to create a separate chart sheet then your recorded code
>   could be modified to retain the original sheet as the source for the
>   chart data. When you add a chart sheet it becomes the active sheet.

By the way, you can check the Chart name from the Selection Pane

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Kraft"
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This didn't help since the error remains "Object required"